# How to retrieve selected value from the dropdown list without refreshing the page or form submitting?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am making a drop down menu about brands in a ecommerce website form where i have to enter products. Is there a possible way to retrieve the selected value of the dropdown without using the submit button. Better still, can i use the select option without an enclosing  element. 
If this is possible, how can i retrieve the value of the dropdown by using jquery.

```
function getbrands_add_products(){
    global $con;
    try{
        $query = "select * from brands";
        $stmt = $con->prepare($query);

        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

        echo "<option>Select Brand</option>";

        foreach ($result as $rows) {
            $brand_id = $rows['brand_id'];
            $brand_title = $rows['brand_title'];
            echo "<option value='$brand_id'>$brand_title</option>";
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

This is the function in which i am querying the database and displaying them as a dropdown list for the user to select. How can i access the selected value without using the form submit. Best if it is jquery.

Comment: yes, you should be able to use it without form tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can use it without `<form>` tag.

in fact you can use any form related element without the `<form>` tag.

if you want to use the `<select>` elemet selected value you can use `select.onchange` event.

the element value is selected option value.

html Code:

```
<select id='select'>
    <option value='11'>
        testOption
    </option>
</select>
```

js Code:

```
var select = document.getElementById('select');
select.onchange = function () {
    var value = this.value;
    alert(value);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the reply. This is so simple and effective. I have another problem if you would tell me. Can i store this value into a php variable?

Comment: wich value you talk about?

Comment: The value which is stored in the (var value) variable which is being printed in the alert.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<select>` outside the form but its not the standard way.

you can access the value using javascript jquery. give it an id like

```
<select id="select-box">
<option value = "something"></option>
....
```

and then on jquery use:

```
$("#select-box").on("change",function(){
    var value = $(this).val()
})
```

but it is not the standard way to use select box outside the form